# Not being able to create an end point. Error with specified port

Tags: windows, docker

I use following commands to run my project.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 --rm -v "d:\project1:/var/www/html" myimage....
```

This was running fine till yesterday. But when I tried the same command, I am getting error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint loving_dubinsky on network nat: hnsCall failed in Win32: The specified port already exists. (0x803b0013).
```

I checked if 8080 port is being used or not using following command.

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8080
```

I could not see this port is being used.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank You.

Comment: can you try with `8090:80` to verify its not port issue?  or try this `Stop-Service docker
Get-ContainerNetwork | Remove-ContainerNetwork
Start-Service docker` https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run "docker ps" command.
From "docker ps" output, you will come to know if there is any container which is listening to port 8080.
You can kill that container using "docker kill container_id".
Now your port 8080 will be free.

Comment: Thanks @Shivani. Yes I already did same this morning by killing the container id. I though accept your answer.